# Difficult JSON To Convert To A Spark Dataframe

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've been trying to load a JSON into a pyspark dataframe but I'm struggling a bit here.

This is what I have tried so far (with and without multiline):

```
import json
newJson = json.dumps(testjson)
newdf = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([newJson]))
newdf.display()
```

JSON File:

```
testjson = [
 ('{"id":434, "address" : ["432.432.432.432", "432.432.432.432", "432.432.432.432", "432.432.432.432"]}',), 
 ('{"id":434, "address" : ["432.432.432.432", "432.432.432.432", "432.432.432.432", "432.432.432.432"]}',), 
 ('{"id":434, "address" : ["432.432.432.432", "432.432.432.432", "432.432.432.432", "432.432.432.432"]}',), 
 ('{"id":434, "address" : ["432.432.432.432", "432.432.432.432", "432.432.432.432", "432.432.432.432"]}',), 
 ('{"id":434, "address" : ["432.432.432.432", "432.432.432.432", "432.432.432.432", "432.432.432.432"]}',), 
 ('{"id":434, "address" : ["432.432.432.432", "432.432.432.432", "432.432.432.432", "432.432.432.432"]}',), 
]
```

When trying to display the dataframe, I get "corrupt_record". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: JSON appears to be invalid. Try to run it through a validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting it to a list of strings. Spark cannot understand a list of tuple of strings. Also `json.dumps` is unnecessary because Spark should be able to understand your json input.

```
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([i[0] for i in testjson]))

df.show(truncate=False)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|address                                                             |id |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|[432.432.432.432, 432.432.432.432, 432.432.432.432, 432.432.432.432]|434|
|[432.432.432.432, 432.432.432.432, 432.432.432.432, 432.432.432.432]|434|
|[432.432.432.432, 432.432.432.432, 432.432.432.432, 432.432.432.432]|434|
|[432.432.432.432, 432.432.432.432, 432.432.432.432, 432.432.432.432]|434|
|[432.432.432.432, 432.432.432.432, 432.432.432.432, 432.432.432.432]|434|
|[432.432.432.432, 432.432.432.432, 432.432.432.432, 432.432.432.432]|434|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
```